# CSS table is wider than table settings

Tags: html, css

Why is this page (http://calvoter.org/issues/votereng/votebymail/study/findings.html) so wide. The table with the white background has a 750px image at the top but the page is wider than needed. I made a copy and deleted all the images/tables in the content and the page remained wider than it needs to be. The text was copied from a Word doc to textwrangler then Dreamweaver

The finding.html page is from the same template as http://calvoter.org/issues/votereng/votebymail/study/ocprofile.html which does not have the extra width issue. Thanks for any help.

The page was made with Dreamweaver CS5.5

Comment: Please post the relevant code to your question. This means deciding where you think this could be coming from and showing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `table` is 970 pixels wide. It is stretching to accommodate an image you have in one of the table cells. The image is

```
<img src=​"graphics/​uncounted_ballots.png" width=​"690" height=​"253" hspace=​"100">​
```

This accounts for 890 pixels of width. This is inside a `blockquote` with a margin of 40 on both sides. Add is all up and you get 970 pixels. The difficulty in figuring this out is why we try to use better coding practices. Your HTML is a maze of nested tables and block quote, which makes it almost impossible to decipher.

Answer (score 0):

basically, it comes from bad coding practices. You have enclosed everything inside block quotes, so you have two paths here: just add this to your stylesheet

```
blockquote{margin:0;}
```

the problem here is you will actually lose the blockquote formatting, but if you don't care about it, it will solve your issues at once. You can also add margin:5px or something like that.

The best approach is to simply "kill" those blockquote elements, and use then ONLY when they are intended to be used. The easiest way is to open your source code with a raw text editor (like Notepad, NOT WORD!) and replace any occurrence of `<blockquote>` and `</blockquote>`. Or even better: replace `<blockquote>` with `<div>` and `</blockquote>` with `</div>` (do a backup first!). That will solve it for you.

Answer (score 0):

because you are not set the main part:`<blockquote>`'s width,and it's width will change and enlarge `<table>`'s width.
first,set `<blockquote>`'s width to inherit in main.css line 134:

```
div#main blockquote {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    width:inherit;             /* add this to control blockquote's width */
}
```

then,change some title and img,they are the main reason that blockquote become too large,like these:
[image]

there is no need to have two nesting `<blockquote>` here,delete them.

finally,give a reasonable position of your `<img>` ,like this:

[image]

set `hspace` is not a good habit,you can simply change it or set a compatible css style.and you can delete this attribute here

If this has any help,please let me know.

**UPDATE:**
actually,If you control elements well in `<blockquote>`,you needn't to set it's width.but if you want to reach your expectation,you'd better do this.

Comment: he can't have a bloackquote width since he has nested blockquotes. Basically, he replaced divs with blockquotes, so adding a width will make things even worse

Comment: @Fabio yes,it is not a good solution,I can't understand why he use Dreamweaver and set layout like this..